# JPA many-to-many association delete record in join table during merge

Tags: jpa

I know there are many posts related to my question. But I face this issue even after following steps mentioned in blogs...

The entities are

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CF_SCRIPT")
public class CFScript implements Serializable, Comparable<CFScript> {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "CF_SCRIPT_PARSER", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CF_SCRIPT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PARSER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Parser> parsers;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "PARSER")
public class Parser implements Serializable, Comparable<Parser> {


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parsers")
    private Set<CFScript> scripts;

}
```

Have the following things as posted in blogs - 
1. Implemented equals and hashcode methods
2. Have mappedby in the inverse side

I have 3 script objects associated with one parser - which has 3 records in cf_script_parser join table.
When I add another parser - I should have the same 3 script objects associated to the new parser and 3 more records in join table accounting to 6 records totally.

But here are the following cases I see
1. One of the first three record in join table gets deleted and 3 new records for second parser gets inserted.
2. 3 records for the first parser exists but only 2 for second parser gets inserted.

It should be total of 6 records instead of 5 in join table for both cases above...
Could any one please help where am missing and please let me know if any details required.

Thanks in advance

Adding few more codes - the loggers will iterate device types from scheduledReport object and CFScript from device types and then Parsers.
Scheduled report and device types are out of this discussion because it is CFscript to Parser that has ManyToMany association discussed in this post.

Controller side

```
protected void save(boolean updateOnly) {
        report.setChangeDate(new Date());
        for(DeviceType dt: report.getDeviceTypes()) {
            logger.info("dt name ---> " + dt.getName() + " -- size -- " + dt.getScripts().size());
            for(CFScript script : dt.getScripts()) {
                logger.info("script name --- " + script.getScriptId() + " -- size -- " + script.getParsers().size());
                for(Parser p : script.getParsers())
                    logger.info("parser name ---> " + p.getName());
            }
        }
        if (updateOnly) {
            report = scheduledReportEjbDAO.updateScheduledReport(report);
        }
}
```

and have the same logger statements in the bean

```
public ScheduledReport updateScheduledReport(final ScheduledReport scheduledReport) {
        logger.info("-----------------one-----------------");
        for(DeviceType dt: scheduledReport.getDeviceTypes()) {
            logger.info("dt name ---> " + dt.getName() + " -- size -- " + dt.getScripts().size());
            for(CFScript script : dt.getScripts()) {
                logger.info("script name --- " + script.getScriptId() + " -- size -- " + script.getParsers().size());
                for(Parser p : script.getParsers())
                    logger.info("parser name ---> " + p.getName());
            }
        }
        return updateScheduledReport(scheduledReport, false);
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code that manipulates the data and the `equals()`/`hashCode()` implementations

Comment: Make sure that you are maintaining both sides of your relationships.  If one row from the jointable is being deleted, it is likely because you are removing a CFScript reference to the Parser instance (from the  Set 'parsers') and merging the changes.

Comment: Chris... you are right. When I checked the Parsers associated with the CFScript before merge/persist one of the parser association to CFScript is missing in the collection. But I do not remove it and I do not know how it is missing.   I pass the object by making a call to a method from controller to Bean with the help of a lookup object... When i checked with logs I see the entire collection when passing object and in the Bean when I iterate over collection one of the parser object is missing in the collection... I will post my code in few mins... Thanks Chris and Andrei :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue(having same number of records in both controller and Bean) got solved by changing Set to Collection in both CFScript and Parser.